# How would I be able to dynamically update an angular table using material table?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-frontend, angular-material-table

Currently, what I have is this.

```
export class TableComponent<T> implements OnInit {

    displayedColumns: Array<string> = [];
    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<T> = new MatTableDataSource();

    constructor(public asmErrorServ: AssemblyErrorService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.displayedColumns = ['Message Type', 'Message', 'Message Date'];
        this.dataSource = (<any>this.asmErrorServ).asmErrorLog;
    }
}
```

The this.datasource gets updated from the asmErrorServ which has an array that stores errors or warnings real-time. That part of the  code appears like this in the errorservice.

```
export class AssemblyErrorService{
...

error(message: string): void {
        let newError: asmMessage = { type: 'error', message: message, time: Date.now() };
        this.asmErrorLog.push(newError);

        this._snackBar.open(this.generateSnackbarString(newError), 'Dismiss', {
            duration: 3000,
            horizontalPosition: this.horizontalPosition,
            verticalPosition: this.verticalPosition,
            panelClass: ['red-snackbar', 'login-snackbar'],
        });
    }
}
```

The out looks like this and the table does not seem to get updated real-time. I was wondering on how to fix it if there's a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to re-initialize the data source property, like below:

```
this.asmErrorLog.push(newError);
this.dataSource.data = this.asmErrorLog;
```

Now the table will be updated in real time.

Comment: It does not work at all. I just wanted to clarify that both the pieces of codes are in different files and classes.

Comment: Declare the dataSource varibale in a common service file with getter and setter, so that you can access the same in different components.

Then in your AssemblyErrorService file use the dataSource  setter method and update the datasource property with the new asmErrorLog data.